# Write to a txt file using windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, writefile

I am trying to write some lines to a a txt file through an ATL application. Below is the fragment of code I use:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, 
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL, 
            CREATE_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);

        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

        std::list<CString> helpList;
        std::list<CString>::iterator it;
        helpList.push_back(L"First Line\r\n");
        helpList.push_back(L"Second Line");

        for(it=helpList.begin(); it!=helpList.end(); ++it)
            WriteFile( hFile, (*it).GetString(), (*it).GetLength(), &dwBytesWritten, NULL );

        CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Notwithstanding everything is working right, nothing is finally written to the file. What should I change in the code?

Comment: Have you checked that the call to `CreateFile` actually succeeds? The same with the `WriteFile` calls?

Comment: Did you close the file handle after writing to it with `CloseHandle(hFile)`?

Comment: dwShareMode  = Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access.
Assuming that the file which already exists, should not be shared.

Comment: Ok, a not fulfilled if-statement above prevented the programm from reaching the given lines of code. After correcting it though, the only line that stands in the txt file looks like : FNUL iNUL rNUL sNUL tNUL SNUL eNUL cNUL oNUL nNUL dNUL. Any idea what provoked that?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

1. Close the handle to the file using `CloseHandle()`
2. The length argument for `WriteFile()` is in bytes but you're specifying characters. Since you're using wide chars you need to multiple the length value by the size of the char.